I need help with trailing edge dimmer implementation
I'm trying to implement trailing edge dimmer for 220 V/50 Hz < 100 W AC load (LED drivers compatible with trailing edge dimming) and would appreciate review of my circuit - will it work or burst in fireworks? I'm absolute beginner so very stupid mistakes might be there.
First what I was trying to achieve:
I wanted to create isolated (by optocouplers) high voltage sub-circuit which would feed zero crossing signals into microcontrollers and also have logic level control line which would turn on/off MOSFETs. I want to leave the timing of MOSFET switch on/off to microcontroller.
For driving low voltage part (optocoupler transistor side/MOSFET gate) I'm using AC-DC 220/12 V power supply.
For zero crossing circuit I'm placing diode bridge so I could catch zero cross signal at each AC half-wave also adding 22 kΩ resistor to limit current via optocoupler (PC814) diode.
For control part I'm trying to use 2 logic level MOSFETs: STP10NK60Z.
Gate is driven by 4N33 optocoupler where current is also limited by R4 resistor so not to overload optocoupler and weak power supply.
I'm placing resistor R5 resistor across MOSFET gate and source to pull down and stabilize MOSFET gate.
Microcontroller will be powered by separate ACDC 220/3.3 V power supply.


Update: 2024/11/16
After reading all comments I got back to reading more theory about controlling mosfets as well as about octocouplers and some basics as well. So I'm thinking about adding dedicated mosfet driver to minimize gate charge and discharge time, also changing zero detection circuit to this one:
https://dextrel.net/dextrel-start-page/design-ideas-2/mains-zero-crossing-detector
This way I should reduce heat by resistors in ZC detection circuit as well as have low voltage on optocoupler.


It looks OK to me.

Your Vcc for your microcontroller needs decoupling. If anything, it would be the gate drive with 10 kohm turn-off. Granted, 50 Hz is slow and 100 W load isn't terrible, but that could be an issue for you. Have you looked at integrated optocoupler+MOSFET offerings like Panasonic AQZ404 where most of this is already taken care of for you?

Thanks! Could you help me understand the nature of issues I could be facing? Direct pins will have currents only 6ma and 10ma - sounds like very small ripples if any? And mosfet  and octocouple driving comes from separate power supply and also currents limited with resistors.
Would definitely look at optomosfets as well.

Your MOSFETs have gate capacitance and you will have limited drive to high from your optocoupler and very limited current to drive to low from your 10 kohm pull-down. Check the datasheet for your MOSFET and model it as just a capacitor and calculate your times. Check the SOAR graph of your MOSFET from switching 100 mA at basically 230*sqrt(2) if it will survive at all. If it does, how much losses will it suffer from the slow switching?

I just bought a house, been looking at tools. My brain read your title as "hedge trimmer" instead of "edge dimmer"...

@pipe Husqvarna 322HD60. The BMS in the battery ones are garbage.


Base should be left open on the 4N33 (or a high-value resistor to emitter), otherwise it will stay on all the time.
I think you intended to tie the (-) output of the isolated DC-DC to the sources. of Q1, Q2. Otherwise bad things will happen.
With a 10kΩ load the 4N33 will take almost a millisecond to turn off, not even counting for dissipating the gate charges) maybe that's a bit on the long side for you. You could use  a logic-output isolator.
(I stopped looking for additional things at this point.֫..)

Thank you! Could you please elaborate on why DC (-) not connecting to mosfet sources could lead to bad things - what could happen and why?
My thinking was: I connected DC (-) directly to AC neutral to have common neutral/zero. Also sources flow back to neutral wire via diodes, so I would not expect significant voltage drop either.
So changing 10k to 1k should not affect gate charging time by a lot, but should cut discharge time ~x10, right?

You want to have control voltage between MOSFET gate and source. More than about 20V  exceeds the absolute maximum rating. You can lower the 10kΩ to increase the turn-off speed, subject to what minimum CTR (current transfer ratio) you have on the optocoupler and the LED drive current.

A few questions:

You're switching neutral rather than live. If you can justify it then that's OK but it does make in-the-field debugging a bit more difficult.
F1 says "100W". What's that about?
R5 is pulling to the mid-point between the MOSFET sources but the DC PSU negative is connected to NEUT. It should be connected between the Q1 and Q2 sources. [I've modified this point after speff analysed it better than me.]
D2 and D3 are different part numbers. 1N4007 and 1N4008. Is that deliberate?
Are D2 and D3 required? Would the intrinsic diodes in Q1 and Q2 do the job?
Be aware that your zero-cross opto won't turn on until the input voltage is high enough. Your software will have to figure out where the real zero-cross is and allow for hysteresis, if any, in the MCU GPIO input.

I haven't check component power ratings, etc.

From the comments:


Not sure if I understand what it means that I'm switching neutral - you mean that load is placed between neutral wire and mosfet drain and not between live and mosfet drain?


No, I'm just pointing out that on most AC circuits such as your home lighting that you switch the live rather than the neutral.


Specs for PC814 says that typical forward voltage of input is 1.2V. And it should be reached in 12uS.


I think you've forgotten the effect of R1, 10 kΩ. You won't get 1 mA flowing until the mains voltage reaches \$ V = IR = 1m \times 10k = 10 \ \text V \$. You'd need to figure out at what LED current your opto output will turn on adequately and redo my calculation. Based on a 1 mA turn-on I reckon that's a 100 μs delay.
I think your best way out of this is to watch for the zero-cross signal to turn off, start a timer, and see how long it takes before it turns back on again. Divide the result by two, and store that value as ZC_delay. Now when the zero-cross signal turns off, wait for a time ZC_delay and then trigger your internal ZC event.

Thank you for the feedback!


Not sure if I understand what it means that I'm switching neutral - you mean that load is placed between neutral wire and mosfet drain and not between live and mosfet drain?


I meant a fuse for 0.5A/220V, but probably it's too close to burnout ratings and I should go with 1A (and fix the label :).


Mistake. Should be the same.


After reading specs better it looks they are not needed at all.




Specs for PC814 says that typical forward voltage of input is 1.2V. And it should be reached in 12uS. Can this have any significance in this application or am I overlooking something else (you mentioned couple of volts)?

One of the ideas was to use ZC signals to start timer for switch-on with negative time offset applied (meaning I can start switch on before next ZC occurs). This offset could be manually tuned, but I'm not sure how can it be done without osciloscope (don't have one).

See the update.
